# Is there any way to reset the field error on Kwes Forms when the field is hidden?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am using Kwes Form to implement multistep form so the problem I am facing is that when the field is hidden the validation is still on that field is there any way to disable validation when the field is hidden (not usable).

[image: Video showing about the error]